# Unable to print out a property in json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am dynamically adding a new property(object) into the existing object.

Here is my code:

```
.then(transactionDetails => {
            console.log(transactionDetails);
            if(transactionDetails != null){
                transactionDetails["nextDueDate"];
                for(var i = 0; i < transactionDetails.length; i++){
                    if(transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment1_isPaid === false){
                        nextDueDate = {
                            installment1_dueAmount:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment1_dueAmount,
                            installment1_dueDate:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment1_dueDate
                        }
                    }else if(transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment2_isPaid === false){
                        nextDueDate = {
                            installment2_dueAmount:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment2_dueAmount,
                            installment2_dueDate:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment2_dueDate
                        }
                    }else if(transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment3_isPaid === false){
                        nextDueDate = {
                            installment3_dueAmount:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment3_dueAmount,
                            installment3_dueDate:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment3_dueDate
                        }
                    }else if(transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment4_isPaid === false){
                        nextDueDate = {
                            installment2_dueAmount:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment4_dueAmount,
                            installment2_dueDate:transactionDetails[i].customers_installment_detail.installment4_dueDate
                        }
                    }
                    transactionDetails[i]["nextDueDate"] = nextDueDate;
                }
                res.json({response:transactionDetails});
            }else{
                res.json({response:"No active transaction."});
            }
        })
```

I am dynamically adding `nextDueDate`. I am able to print out the value in console by typing `transactionDetails[0].nextDueDate` but however when I try to print it out the whole object in JSON, `nextDueDate` is missing and just could not be printed out. Any reasons ?

Comment: Isn't your console statement above at the top? I mean you are adding the dynamic property later.

Comment: As @YousafHassan said you console.log for transactionDetails is executed before you add nextDueDate. Moreover, this line transactionDetails["nextDueDate"]; has no sense.

Comment: @YousafHassan I put a breakpoint at res.json({response:transactionDetails});

Comment: @kylas that is because transactionDetails["nextDueDate"]; does not do anything. Assign it some value e.g null to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to Sequelize issue according to this thread:
[Add Property to Object that is returned by Sequelize FindOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426683/add-property-to-object-that-is-returned-by-sequelize-findone)

I fixed this by adding a virtual column in my model.

```
nextDueDate: Sequelize.VIRTUAL
```