# res.render doesn't load sequelize datavalue

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

So, what I am trying to do is add a property to a model instance. As mentioned here [Add Property to Object that is returned by Sequelize FindOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426683/add-property-to-object-that-is-returned-by-sequelize-findone)
 and the sequelize docs. Adding a property with the use of `setDataValue()` will work.

Consider this example.

```
instance = await model.findOne({where: ...})
newColumnValue = instance.definedColumn * 15;
instance.setDataValue("newColumn", newColumnValue);

//calling data through json
//this works fine
res.json({data: instance});
```

I can see my new column and its value with above code. However, I want to render my handlebars template. So, I do...

```
res.render("hbsFile", {data: instance});
```

And in my .hbs file it can't seem to read the `newColumn` using `{{data.newColumn}}`

However if I do this

**Workaround 1**

```
//transform my instance to JSON
instance.setDataValue("newColumn", newColumnValue);
instance = instance.get({plain: true});
res.render("hbsFile", {data: instance});
```

**Workaround 2**

```
//instead of using setDataValue
//associate property like in POJO
instance.newColumn = newColumnValue;
res.render("hbsFile", {data: instance});
```

With both the solutions, I can access `{{data.newColumn}}` in my .hbs file.

**Questions**

Question #1: Which **workaround** (if any) is the correct approach? What's the alternative?

Question #2: Why doesn't express `res.render()` call sequelize's `toJSON()` method like `res.json()` does?

Comment: Is the column 'newColumn' defined in the model? Additionally have you tried sending `instande.dataValues`? (if, so, what was the result)

Comment: Obviously, no. Otherwise, it would be accessible with the model instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Express's `res.json` calls `JSON.stringify()` as stated in the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json), which in turn calls the instance's (Sequelize's) `toJSON`.

On the other hand `res.render` calls `app.render` which calls `view.render` which in the end calls the templating engine. During that whole process various options are merged but, as far as I managed to notice in both the code and the docs, no `toJSON` is called on the data you provided. The object is just passed during the whole process to the templating engine, and if the templating engine is trying to access the property via `instance['newColumn']` it could possibly read undefined since `setDataValue` implementation does: `instance.dataValues[key] = value`.

Sequelize's instances store their values in the `dataValues` object and use getters to get the values when you are accessing them via dot notation. That can lead to some situations where the getter isn't mapped correctly or is unable to retrieve a property form `dataValues` for some reason. I have personally had this problem when spreading objects into a new one and passing that new object somewhere else.

One workaround that you can always use is doing `{data: instance.dataValues}` or use the plain option as you have discovered (which basically does the same thing in most situations, but is cleaner since `dataValues` aren't really intended to be accessed directly).

A second workaround is of course calling the `toJSON` function yourself and then parsing the result back into a plain object.

Both  of these approaches are not only perfectly valid, but also good design because you should not be passing "tracked" ORM models as view models (which you are doing in your second workaround). Doing that exposes your database to layers of the application that should not have access to it and might cause unexpected behaviours.

---

**TLDR:** Workaround 1 is the better approach

Comment: +1 for the explanation. Why is exposing sequelize objects while rendering a bad design? If so, shouldn't sequelize implement it?

Comment: It's not a problem to expose them while rendering, but to expose them in the layers of the app that should never communicate with the database. A dumb example is what if your templating engine called `data.existingColumn = 'foo'; data.save();`. If data was a sequelize object then those changes could possibly end up stored in the database, something that that layer should probably not able to do.

Comment: And no, sequelize shouldn't implement that because while you're in your repositories, services and possibly controllers you probably want to have a tracked object like that so that you can persist changes to the instance, but once that data is passed out of the controller you don't want to be able to do that and sequelize has no way of knowing in which layer the object is because that all depends on your architecture and design.